# Getting callback even when screen rotates in android (MVP Design Pattern)

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments

Okay, this might be stale, but i really need to understand what the best practice will be and not how to easily bypass this either by disabling screen orientation or any other means.

I have a login screen and when the user clicks on login button it should go to the server and authenticate and return a response.
My problem is if the screen rotates my fragment might not receive a callback of the response data.

**I'm trying out an MVP design pattern on android.**

```
public void registerSignInEvent(){
    this.signInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = usernameEdit.getText().toString();
            String password = passwordEdit.getText().toString();
            authPresenter.loginUser(username, password, 1);
          }
       });
    }
```

I've thought of the following...

1. Use a **service** to handle the login to the server, when its done the service updates the storage e.g `is_login=false` or `true` then use a **`LocalBroadcastManager`** to broadcast the event to the **view**(Fragment)
   so it can query the `presenter` to know the login state.
2. Use a Fragment with setRetainIntance(true); to handle the presenter initialization and the presenter will trigger callback to methods of the activity e.g onLoginSuccess //confusing myself

**Problem**

A. the problem with my no.1 thought is that when my loginFragment is onPause at that moment, the broadcast receiver is unregistered, so it might not receive the event. plus i don't even know if it makes sense.

B. Its looks complicated with MVP pattern

The pattern really might not matter, i don't really need code snippet tho, I just need to understand the process that **best** fits the situation.

NOTE: My Presenter communicates with the view(fragment/activity) via the view interface, vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

You could try storing the user in the database/sharedprefs whenever you receive the response from the login, if a rotation occurs and the login-fragment gets reattached without receiving the necessary callbacks (which is the problem you're describing) you could add a check if the user is "already" logged in  (by checking if the user exists in the db/sharedprefs in onResume of the loginactivity) and forward the user to the next activity or fragment from there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I use this cool method to keep presenter alive even if activity recreated: [Presenter surviving orientation changes with Loaders](https://medium.com/@czyrux/presenter-surviving-orientation-changes-with-loaders-6da6d86ffbbf#.nw93uykok). It detaches and attaches activity in onStop and onStart.

Need to mention also, that your second choice with persistent fragment in widely used, e.g. by [Fernando Cejas](http://fernandocejas.com/). I've learned [clean architecture](http://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/) approach with his [articles](http://fernandocejas.com/2015/07/18/architecting-android-the-evolution/), and he uses [setRetainState(true)](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture/blob/master/presentation/src/main/java/com/fernandocejas/android10/sample/presentation/view/fragment/UserListFragment.java).

And still your question is driving me crazy as well. Only solution I've found so far is ugly as hell. But it should work. Idea: after work done, I check if view is attached. If so, I proceed normally. I there is no view, that we are in the middle of rotation. So I have flag, that indicate, that work is done. I turn it on. Also I cache any needed data. And wait for the next view attaching. Where I check that flag.

Here is my code snippet. I'm not proud of it thought.

```
class SplashPresenter extends BasePresenter<SplashView> {

    private final SplashInteractor splashInteractor;
    private boolean isSplashWorkStarted;
    private boolean isSplashWorkFinished;
    private boolean isSplashWorkError;
    private Throwable splashWorkError;

    @Inject
    SplashPresenter(SplashInteractor splashInteractor) {
        this.splashInteractor = splashInteractor;
    }

    @Override
    public void attachView(SplashView mvpView) {
        super.attachView(mvpView);
        if (isSplashWorkFinished) {
            getMvpView().showApplicationUi();
        } else if (isSplashWorkError) {
            getMvpView().showError(splashWorkError.getMessage());
        }
    }

    void executeSplashWork() {
        if (!isSplashWorkStarted) {
            splashInteractor.execute(new SplashInteractorSubscriber());
            isSplashWorkStarted = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyed() {
        splashInteractor.unsubscribe();
    }

    private final class SplashInteractorSubscriber extends Subscriber<Void> {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            if (isViewAttached()) {
                getMvpView().showApplicationUi();
            } else {
                isSplashWorkFinished = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            if (isViewAttached()) {
                getMvpView().showError(e.getMessage());
            } else {
                isSplashWorkError = true;
                splashWorkError = e;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Void v) {
        }
    }
}
```